# Copy/Paste from Word Document to Web

Tags: microsoft-word

Trying to save time and I need an easy way to make sure copied text from word is UTF-8 compatible for the web. Generally I have to copy and paste 4 or 5 pages of text at a time. Going through it and correcting characters individually is a real time waster. Anyone have any ideas? Is there a setting in Microsoft Word I might be missing?

Answer (score 1):

Eric, if you are pasting into some sort of CMS the text editors often have a special, paste from "microsoft word" function. Old HTMLAREA3.0 as well as current JCE used in Joomla and wordpress have this feature.

Comment: Also TinyMCE with plugins has the same button.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly save the Word document as HTML from within Microsoft Word and then copy and paste the HTML which Word has produced, it will probably have a lot of formatting information and other clutter that you don't need but possibly worth a try.

Comment: This is not correct way, because this function generates a lot of unused tags.

Comment: @netme I agree, but the author of the question didn't specify that they wanted nicely formatted and concise HTML particularly since they say that they are trying to save time.